# Junit TemporaryFolder permission not working

Tags: java, linux, windows, junit, permissions

I have a unit test that is running fine in Linux (Ubuntu 12.04) but when running the same code in Windows I am not getting an exception. Basically what the test is doing is changing the folder permission and then attempting to read and write to it to trigger some specific exception messages depending on the given permission.

```
@Rule
public TemporaryFolder testFolder = new TemporaryFolder();

[...]

    testFolder.create();
    File folder = testFolder.newFolder();
    if(!folder.setReadable(false)){
        Assert.fail("Unable to remove reading right");
    }
```

This code sample works in Linux but always fails in Windows. Apparently the unit test when running is unable to set the readable attribute to false. I thought about some permission problem but the temporary folder is created in : user_folder\AppData\Local\Temp in which I have all permissions.

Is there something I missed from the documentation? How else could I remove reading and writing permission on the folder?